# CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement FirstApp

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

namespace FirstApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cf");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("bv");
            Console.ReadLine();
            ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConsoleColor.Black;` isn't an operation. It can't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConsoleColor.Black;` is an enum value, not a function call. That does nothing. What you probably want is

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; // Set the console background to black
```